# Remove columns with values 0 or 999999

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, data-analysis

I am working with a large data set with 400 columns some of the columns have all values zero and others have all zeros with few '999999999'. I want to get rid of such columns. I was able to do it for the columns containing just zeroes but not sure hoe to do it for columns containing  zeroes and '999999999'

Following is the code for removing zeroes-

```
 df = df.loc[:, (df != 0).any(axis=0)]
```

It is fairly simple I know. But if anyone can help me with the next part that would be awesome. Thanks

Comment: what is your data contained in ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `.isin()` to condition on several values:

```
df = df.loc[:, (~df.isin([0, 99999999])).any(axis=0)]
```

Comment: SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
df = df.loc[:, ((df != 0) & (df != 999999999)).any(axis=0)]
```

Example:

```
>>> df
           a  b  c
0          0  0  1
1          0  0  0
2  999999999  0  5


>>> df.loc[:, ((df != 0) & (df != 999999999)).any(axis=0)]
   c
0  1
1  0
2  5
```